# How can I use Whatsapp Web on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, whatsapp

I can't use Whatsapp web of Firefox since the last few months. It still runs without any slightest issue on Chrome. It's the same on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried to clear cookies, and restart the browser several times, but to no effect.

I see the loading screen indefinitely, as in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I have the opposite problem, Firefox works and Chrome doesn't: [How is web.whatsapp.com supposed to work on an Ubuntu desktop? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454410/how-is-web-whatsapp-com-supposed-to-work-on-an-ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: I closed this question because it's a troubleshooting like question. It might be better suited for [su], [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se].

Comment: I strongly disagree with your opinion here, @Rubén. This question is perfectly related to the behavior of a web app (Whatsapp), not an OS (Unix, Ubuntu or Windows). Please open my question.